# ArangoDB: Problem with login when connecting from the same server where Arango is running

Tags: node.js, docker, server, arangodb

I have a problem with logging in to ArangoDB from the same server where ArangoDB is running.

We have a running Docker container of ArangoDB in a remote machine which IP is, let's say, 95.123.123.123:8529. When connecting to the DB from our dockerized NodeJS app, which is running in my local machine, in the following way:

```
import { Database } from 'arangojs';

try {
    const db = new Database({
       url: 'http://95.123.123.123:8529', 
    });
    db.useDatabase('flex');
    db.useBasicAuth('root', 'password');
} catch(err) {
   log('database login failed', err);
}
```

Login works just fine.

However, when I build our app, dockerize it, and deploy it to the same server where the ArangoDB is running, and using the same method above to login, login fails. Our server app logs then the following error `database login failed, Error: EIO: i/o error, write`.

How come the login works when connecting from the local machine, but it is not, when logging in from the same remote machine where the Arango is running?

Comment: Maybe you need docker to allow the containers to talk to each other?

Comment: They can talk when the dockerized server app is running in my local machine.

Comment: This error is generated by javascript, and not by arango. I can suggest two things for you to check. Check if the machine has enough space after deploying your app `df -h`, and check if the dependencies of your nodejs app are all installed correctly.

Comment: I checked the free space, there's plenty of space in the remote machine (12G). Also, dependencies should be fine since I'm having no issues with the same docker image in the local machine. I build the image in the local machine and it works without issues. But when it's deployed on to the remote server where the arango is, it won't.

Comment: Can you try connecting with localhost / 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Can you login to the database using its interface? Go to the browser, and put the following url: 95.123.123.123:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html#collections

Comment: Yes, login works fine. Actually got it working finally. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working. The issue was using the public IP address instead of the internal one when the server app and arango were in the same server.

Running

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <arangocontainerid>
```

gives the internal IP address of the container: `172.17.0.4`. And then making the NodeJS server app to point to `tcp://172.17.0.4:8529` instead of the public arango IP address, made it work.

However, when accessing to the DB the from the local machine or any machine which is not in the same server with arango, obviously the public IP address `http://95.123.123.123:8529` must then to be used.